# Is runtime-compiled-class instantiation & usage possible in Java without reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, compilation, runtime

I would like to know if there exists any kind of library or workaround to use my runtime compiled classes ( I dynamically generate my classes, writing .java, then compiling them in .class all of this happens at runtime) without using a reflection library?

Loading using reflection I always have to work like this:

```
//path where my newly generated classes are 
File file = new File("e:\\tmp");
// Convert File to a URL
URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class cls = cl.loadClass("eu.dataaccess.footballpool.TGoal");
// Create an instance of the class just loaded
Object o = cls.newInstance();
Method method2 = cls.getDeclaredMethod("getIMinute");
Object result2 = method2.invoke(o);
```

My question is if it's somehow possible to use at runtime

```
TGoal x = new TGoal();
```

and

```
x.getIMinute();
```

EDIT: It seems it is impossible to act the way I hoped to. I modify my question so: is it possible to load a whole package at runtime, in a way that the classes of the loaded package are able to communicate each other without the method.invoke, meanwhile the main activation of the package is done with the method invoke() ?

I tried without any luck, i have some "error: cannot find symbol", it seems the runtime-loaded classes can't communicate each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using the reflection api you have to instantiate classes via the new operator. This requires having the class file at compile time. So it is not possible. If your class TGoal is implementing an Interface IGoal, then you can cast your Object o to IGoal. This enables you to work with your Object like with any other object without using the reflection api.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
x.getIMinute();
```

by using interfaces, but AFAIK you cannot create new class instances without reflection.

Instead, to call methods of your dynamically created objects, you 
can declare an interface:

```
public interface MinuteGetter{
   public int getIMinute();
}
```

Your dynamic objects have to implement his, than you can do:

```
Class cls = cl.loadClass("eu.dataaccess.footballpool.TGoal");
// Create an instance of the class just loaded
MinuteGetter o = (MinuteGetter) cls.newInstance();
o.getIMinute();
```

If applying an interface to your code is not an option for you, you can try to give a try to AnonymousClassLoader. See this [detailed post about it](http://blog.headius.com/2008/09/first-taste-of-invokedynamic.html). 
It work only on Java 7, and please note that I never used it, so how don't know if it offer better performance than reflection.

Comment: At compile time i don't have neither Interface or Class code generated yet, so i don't have the interface MinuteGetter at compile time

Comment: Yes i have full control on the runtime generated code, but it may vary from time to time, and I'm not able to provide a generic interface that serves all the cases

Comment: I saw you EDIT. I also think that avoid reflection is not possible in your situation. Anyway it's possible for sure to have an entry point in the dynamic package (I've aleady done similar things) If you can add some code in your answer that reproduce your error, I could try to help you find the bug.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you have to create the Code at runtime? The easiest way is to avoid this.

If the `TGoal x = new TGoal()` doesn't have to happen in this program, then create a main function in the generated code and start a second java application.

Comment: I am generating specific clients from run-time provided wsdl, so I don't see any other way of doing this except stopping the whole platform and rechange the source for each new wsdl